# avoid doing != null when calling length

Tags: java

i have a system where a user can enter animal names

i have a form:

```
enter your first animal name: ________________
enter your second animal name: ________________
enter your tird animal name: ________________
```

im checking the lenght to make sure the size of the string is < 25

but on the form if a user does not enter a name i will get null since i have 3 variable :

- animalname1
- animalname2
- animalname3

if a user does not enter a name, the field is null and throws nullable exception

```
if (animalname1.length() >= 25) {
// my error
}
```

i would like to avoid doing and keep my code simple:

```
if (animalname1 != null && animalname1.length() >= 25) {
// my error
}
```

i am learning Optional but I can't make it work.

i try:

```
Optional<Object> q = Optional
    .ofNullable(x)
    .map((o) -> {
        if (o.length() >= 25) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
});
```

but that does not work

is there a way i can do something like:

```
boolean hasError1 = Optional
    .isNotNull((o) -> {
        if (o.length() >= 25) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    ).else(false);
```

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final boolean hasAnyLonger = Stream.of(name1, name2, name3)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(String::length)
    .anyMatch(len -> len >= 25);
```

Answer (score 6):

`if (animalname1 != null && animalname1.length() >= 25)` looks cleaner and simpler to be honest.

You could also create a helper method:

```
private static boolean invalidAnimal(String animalName) {
  return animalName != null && animalName.length() >= 25;
}
```

Then your conditions become cleaner:

```
if (invalidAnimal(animalName1)) //error
```

And if you want to test them all at once, you can write:

```
if (Stream.of(animal1, animal2, animal3).anyMatch(MyClass::invalidAnimal)) //error
```